# Find callers of a method

Tags: java, static-analysis, call-graph

I am trying to check if methods that acquire a resource also release it. What is the best tool to use to find out callers of a method in the classes in a single jar file? Can I do this with `CheckStyle` or `FindBugs`? How?

I guess I can do this using `BCEL` or such-like, but I have never worked with byte-code before and would take too long to do this.

Searching for "java call graph" did not find anything useful, but this seems to be a very basic functionality so I  probably missed a good match. However, I would like to not have to generate the entire call graph on this very large project.

Comment: It's hard to make a recommendation without knowing what kind of resources you are trying to audit. Depending on the 'what' and the 'how' you might want to take a look at an AOP tool like Javassist, or a call flow analysis tool like Soot.

Comment: @Perception I came across Soot in my search which I think will do the job but it will require some programming. I am hoping to be able to find something I can use immediately for *arbitrary* resources -- say I want to find all methods in a jar which call `SomeResource.acquire`

Comment: Certainly FindBugs has features for finding unclosed streams. I don't know how generalised that support is.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yes, I know it can detect unclosed stream but I can't tell if it can handle my requirement

Comment: @MiserableVariable - Soot does require quite a bit of programming. FindBugs can check for leaky database resources, in addition to streams, so that might be the way to go.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good tool to do a call trace http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacalltracer/. BTW if you use eclipse it will give you the trace if you select the method and do a "Call Hierarchy".

Comment: The eclipse refactoring tool has such a functionality, but I can't explain how to use it from outside eclipse.

Comment: You can have a look at the implementation of [Eclipse Call Hierarchy](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/callhierarchy/CallHierarchyViewPart.java.htm). Maybe that helps a bit.

Comment: You pointed at some UI functionality...I do know Eclipse has a call hierarchy and that it is open source, do you have any specific information?

Comment: I just wanted to give you some "inspiration" for your own implementation.

Comment: But how do I take inspiration from a code which *displays* the call graph when I am trying to *create* the call graph?

Comment: there are several projects in the product, some ant, some maven. Not all of them use Eclipse. So a solution tied to eclipse does not work.

Comment: @Perception the resources are neither db connection nor streams, so FindBugs cannot find these bugs.

Comment: @raddykrish the tool you referenced creates a run-time call graph, I am looking for static analyis

Comment: @MiserableVariable sorr about that...could you please check this link https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph seems like it might fit your requirement.

Comment: Uh, look at the (Eclipse open source) code that implements the call graph extraction, which is clearly a necessary step before the call graph is displayed?

Comment: @IraBaxter I am not looking for complete call graph actually, just callers of one (actually two) methods. Wading through Eclipse source code is a huge task, and I won't be surprised if it works off source code, where I am looking to search in .jar files.

Comment: @MiserableVariable:  then you want a tool like Soot, that processes byte code.  I believe it too is open source, but I suspect (I have no specific experience) it has APIs to compute various properties.

Comment: @IraBaxter yes, my hope of finding something like `grep-java-call <signature> <list of jar files>` is a futile. But thank you for your reply, I came across DMS during my search and though it was too heavyweight for what I currently need you obviously know a lot about this subject so thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but I believe [Java Callgraph](https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph) will do what you want.

Comment: @MiserableVariable.   When it comes to static analysis facts, you're unlikely to find any tool with command line interface to extract such general facts, mostly because such facts in isolation aren't very useful. Normally one has to extract the facts (as some kind of data structure) and then traverse them to look for special cases of interest (e.g., "traverse call facts looking for call to specific method X").  So you tend to find such extractors as internal APIs inside tools (we have such an API inside DMS for Java source code call facts) where they can be used. [Thanks for the compliment].

Comment: @raddykrish java-callgraph is doing the job for me. If you cpnvert it to an answer I will accept and give you the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Yes, `Java Callgraph` does the job. Another poster suggested it first so I will wait for him to create an answer that I can accept.

Comment: Check [this link](https://github.com/gousiosg/java-callgraph). Seems like it might meet your requirements.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I converted it as an answer. thanks